# MonitoredHost class is not present in the jdk

Tags: java, jvm

Class `MonitoredHost`  is not present in the java version i am using which is

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

The api doc says it available under package `sun.jvmstat.monitor` but the package doesn't appears in my jdk.

Am i missing anything ? Is there any other equivalent class for this which I can use from my java app?

More specifically which java apis can i use for reading all the running java process? (i.e something similar to `jps` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some more research I found a good article [here](http://mostly-about-java.blogspot.in/2013/06/how-to-get-process-id-for-any-jvm.html) which says that its present in tools.jar

- But here are few catches in using the `sun.jvmstat.monitor` package :

  - The tool.jar is a library distributed with Oracle JDK but not JRE!
  - You cannot get `tool.jar` from Maven repo; configure it with Maven is a bit tricky.
  - The tool.jar probably contains platform dependent (native?) code so it is not easily    distributable
  - It runs under assumption that all (local) running JVM apps are "monitorable".